# Twitter bootstrap dropdown not working when change to other page?

Tags: html, css, grails, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I am adding a dropdown menu in my web page using twitter bootstrap. But the dropdown only works when I am at the homepage. When I navigate to other subpages, it doesnt work anymore. Please let me know how to make it work on other page. Thanks

Comment: Could you add some more information, code, etc? What isn't working with the dropdown box?

Comment: Probably a relative path problem. Make sure the CSS and JS are loaded in all pages. And post some code or at least a detailed description of what's happening.

Comment: You must have forgotten to remove the default <a href="#". Replace the # with your desired html page, or if it is a dynamic one, try using a relative path.